# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, resttemplate, jackson-databind

Am using Spring boot 2.1.1 am getting below error while using 
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at 
    org.springframework.http.converter.json
    .Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:617) ~[spring-web- 
    5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init> 
    (MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:50) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at
```

From my pom:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

While creating the org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate object I am getting this exception

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

`com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper` is from an optional Jackson extension (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml). You can include it in your project by adding the following to the pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

In case the version for this Maven artifact is not defined in the parent pom, you must add it yourself, e.g. for the latest version

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You may need more dependencies, so check the link from above.