# Not able to add XML mapper for the XML input Object : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb, objectmapper, jackson-dataformat-xml, xmlmapper

after searching for a while, I cannot get the correct version of the Jackson jar and what Jackson jars I need to use. I am not able to get the exact solution tried adding all the applicable jars for the same but my application has not started.
Using the following jars..

```
<spring.version>5.3.23</spring.version>
    <jackson.version>2.13.2</jackson.version
```

> 

I am trying to add the **Object mapper** for both types of input and output, **JSON and XML** with the help of a message converter Here is the code in *-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven >
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
                        <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_EMPTY"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <!-- Added this bean configuration for XML serialization  -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper">
                        <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_EMPTY"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Here are my parent pom entries: Jackson jar version is `2.13.2`

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <!-- upgraded due to vulnerabilities in 2.13.2 -->
                <version>2.13.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> 
                <version>${jackson.version}</version> 
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-provider</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
                <!-- <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions> -->
            </dependency>
```

**after the success clean and build I am getting ClassNotFoundException while starting tomee, even after I have added applicable depencies in respective pom.xml.**

Here is the exception I am getting from it.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/api-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1155)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:584)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
        at org.apache.openejb.util.classloader.URLClassLoaderFirst.loadClass(URLClassLoaderFirst.java:136)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 39 more
```

**Need to understand the way or path to look what is wrong here, where I need to improve to resolve this ClassNotFoundException**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60421717/14419

Comment: Done the configuration as per the above link. It's not working for me.